# Database isn't receiving values from form using php

Tags: php, html, sql

Im trying to send form data to my sql database but the database isn't receiving any of my values. The name of my database is taxibooking and table name is bookings.

I tried separating the php code in another file and using action on form to access the php code. on clicking submit I was redirected to a blank page with my php file name.

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
Name of customer:<input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
Enter pickup address:<textarea name="padd" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea><br><br>
                                                                            Enter destination address:<textarea name="dadd" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea><br><br>
   Select Taxi type:<select name="taxi"><option value="Viennese      Fiaker">The Viennese Fiaker</option><option value="Indian Auto Rickshaw">Indian Auto Rickshaw</option><option value="Little Yellow">Little Yellow</option><option value="Mumbai Taxi Fiat">Mumbai Taxi Fiat</option><option value="Tricycles">Tricycles</option><option value="Water Taxi">Water Taxi</option><option value="Impeccable Taxi">Impeccable Taxi</option><option value="Red Taxi">Red   Taxi</option></select><br><br>



<input type="submit" value="submit" name="sub">



</form>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","taxibooking");

if(isset($_POST['sub']))
 {

   $n=$_POST['fname'];
   $p=$_POST['padd'];

   $d=$_POST['dadd'];
    $type=$_POST['taxi'];
      $sql="insert into bookings(name,pickup,destination,type)   values        ('$n','$p','$d','$type')";
 mysqli_query($con,$sql);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug and put query on if condition

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo'done';
 }else{
    echo "error".$sql."</br>" . mysqli_error($con);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add parameters on your insert script.

```
$sql="insert into bookings(name,pickup,destination,type) values ('".$n."','".$p."','".$d."','".$type."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a new database with a different  name  with the same table name and properties and now it sort of mysteriously works now. No changes done to the code.